# SQL - Using Selected column to determine data row population?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT cust.Name, rec.ProductID, 
       CASE WHEN rec.IsPaid IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END    
FROM Customer AS [cust]
LEFT JOIN Records AS [rec]
ON cust.CustID = rec.CustID
```

Hi, guys. I wish to know is there a way to return a row of data **ONLY WHEN** *IsPaid* is 1?

Means that if *IsPaid* is 0, the whole row a data will not be selected.

Comment: `where rec.IsPaid = 1`

Comment: That's exactly what it is. Thanks @GordonLinoff  :D

Comment: Add your table with data in question

Comment: haha... i think it's ok.. the above snippet is juz a sample that resembles the real query of my side :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well firstly do you actually need to return rec.IsPaid as 0 or 1?  Because  your query could be simplified to:

```
SELECT cust.Name, rec.ProductID
FROM Customer AS [cust]
LEFT JOIN Records AS [rec]
ON cust.CustID = rec.CustID
WHERE rec.IsPaid IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Lemme giv it a try later when i'm back from work haha... :D thx for the suggestion!